# Why does the default MVC 4 project include minified files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, minify

I'm trying to get my head around bundles in MVC 4. From what I've read, you simply point it at a script or bunch of scripts, give it a name, and it'll bundle them up. If you're not in debug it will also minify them.

Sample Code:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

If it's done dynamically, why does the project have `.min.js` files for every script? Does the minifying process actually just load `.min.js` rather than minify it itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run in debug mode, the .debug.js files are included. If you run in release mode, the .min.js files are included. If the file is not .debug.js or .min.js, it's included in both cases.

In release mode, all the files, are minified and bundled in one file. No matter if they were or not were previously bundled.

I usually have the original, not .min.js or .debug.js files, and let the bundler do all the job of minification.

There is also another important thing you must be aware of: the bundler will reorder the included files according to internal rules. And, if you use wildcards, the files are included alfabetically. This can make fail your scripts if there are dependencies and they are included in the worng order. You can run your site in debug mode to check the order (look at the rendered script tags). If the order is wrong, you can tweak the file names or implement an [IBundleOrderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.ibundleorderer%28VS.110%29.aspx).

This is [a very interesting article on bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).